# Android Application that points to a web app

Tags: android, iphone, web-applications

I have a web application that is optimized for mobile viewing, so that it can be used on all smartphones (Android, iPhone, etc).

The development of the web application is nearing completion, but I would also like to have an actual downloadable app that users can put on their phones. All this app would do is literally point to the web application and ask them to log in.

Is this something that can be easily done, or will I need to develop full fledged Android and iPhone applications separately that interact with my web app somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at PhoneGap and other similar tools for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com) is a tool that essentially will do what you are asking out of the box. If you are somewhat familiar with native development, you can also create a simple app where the main view is a web browser (see [WebView (Android)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) or [UIWebView (iOS)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)).

Comment: Thank you! the first answer was what I needed, but it doesn't support iPhone. I'll look into this more. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://www.appsgeyser.com/).

> Create apps from any web content.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Just need one for iPhone now. Appreciate the help.